# External file write is triggering anti virus pop up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, antivirus

I have created a small game in C#.  The players' location is saved into an external text file called:

GAME_FILE.txt

This file is located in the same folder as the main EXE.

The game loads fine but when the player moves from Location 1 to Location 2, it then writes that to the text file.  But as soon as it writes it, Norton Antivirus flags up the following message:

> Suspicious process attempted to open a file protected by Data Protector
> Target: GAME_FILE.txt

Now, I need to try and fix this because I want to share my game with others and don't want to worry about antivirus warnings appearing on other users PC's.

The code I am using to write to the file, is as follows:

`File.WriteAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "/" + "GAME_FILE.txt", PlayerLocation);`

(where `PlayerLocation` is a string representing the players' location in the game).

Now, this works fine when run inside Visual Studio, but flags up the warning when trying to play the game via the EXE file.

Any help here would be much appreciated, as I want to be able to share my game with others.

Comment: Where is `Application.StartupPath`?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471694/access-denied-to-my-xml-file-while-running-the-executable#comment126328366_71471694

Comment: If you accept it and it works, you could click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make sure you are writing in 'safe' paths. Try to write in public documents or temporary folders.

Also, take a look on this thread.
[My C# app is getting flagged by anti-virus apps. How do I figure out why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297722/my-c-sharp-app-is-getting-flagged-by-anti-virus-apps-how-do-i-figure-out-why)

Comment: Hi Ken, and Douglas.  Thanks for both of your responses.  I think I have fixed it now!  So, 'Application.StartupPath' was pointing to a file on my Desktop (C:\Users\(username)\Desktop\(mygamefolder) and this was causing Norton Anti virus to keep flagging the pop up warning.  However... I have just copied and pasted all my game files to C:\Temp and then ran it from there, and no errors appeared!!  When the location changed for the player, the new location was written to the text file no problems at all and no warnings!  Very pleased indeed with this outcome!  Thanks.